# How to specify who is sending the email with the `mail` gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, smtp, mail-gem

I am sending emails with the `mail` gem, using the very simple code below. When I'm sending an email, the `smtp_account.user_name` and the `smtp_account.from` could be e.g. `support@thebestcompany.com`. This causes the recipient to see that he has received an email from `support` (you know, in his inbox where he can get an overview of his last x emails). How can I specify this, so the recipient gets to see something more interesting, like e.g. `The Best Company`?

```
require 'mail'

class SmtpMails

  def self.send_mails(smtp_account, to, subject, text)
    options = {
      :address              => smtp_account.address,
      :port                 => smtp_account.port,
      :domain               => smtp_account.domain,
      :user_name            => smtp_account.user_name,
      :password             => smtp_account.password,
      :authentication       => smtp_account.authentication,
      :enable_starttls_auto => smtp_account.enable_starttls_auto
    }

    Mail.defaults do
      elivery_method :smtp, options
    end

    mail = Mail.deliver do
      to to
      from smtp_account.from
      subject subject
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add some additional information when specifying the sender of the email. The following code snippet should do what you want:

```
mail = Mail.deliver do
  to to
  from "The Best Company <#{smtp_account.from}>"
  subject subject
end
```

Putting the email address between the `<` and `>` brackets is the standard practice for adding a friendly name for the email being sent.

Answer (score 0):

```
mail.from.addresses
mail.sender.address
```

Try this.

Comment: Hi Sami. I'm not sure this is the solution. The methods you've put in are being used to read emails, not write them.